Integral relationship between Hessian, gradient, and scalar function
Consider a twice differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, its gradient $\nabla f(x)$, and Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x)$. I know how to obtain the gradient and Hessian given $f$ by differentiating each scalar function with respect to each component in the vector space. I have seen the integral relationship between the Hessian and gradient, and gradient and scalar function written this way.
$$ \nabla f(x_2) - \nabla f(x_1) = \int_0^1(\nabla^2f(x_1 + \lambda(x_2 - x_1)) (x_2 - x_1) d\lambda $$
$$ f(x_2) - f(x_1) = \int_0^1 \langle \nabla f(x_1 + \lambda(x_2 - x_1)), (x_2 - x_1) \rangle d\lambda $$
This makes sense dimensionally and somewhat intuitively, but is there a more rigorous derivation? And a side question: given that the path of integration is a straight line between $x_1$ and $x_2$, would this mean that $f$ needs to be "conservative"? Or is that a given since $f$ is a scalar function?

Both of these are the fundamental theorem of calculus applied to $\phi(\lambda) = \nabla f(x_1 + \lambda(x_2 - x_1))$ and $\psi(\lambda) = f(x_1 + \lambda(x_2 - x_1))$.

The second equation is just the fundamental theorem of line integrals. The first equation is the same theorem applied to the scalar functions $f_{x_i}$, the components of $\nabla f$, and using the following representation of the matrix multiplication:
$$
\nabla^2 f(x)y = \begin{pmatrix}\nabla(f_{x_1})^T \\ \vdots \\ \nabla(f_{x_n})^T\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\\vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\langle\nabla(f_{x_1}),y\rangle\\ \vdots\\ \langle\nabla(f_{x_n}),y\rangle\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore we can just apply the fundamental theorem of line integral to each component of $\nabla f$ and represent it in matrix-vector form using the Hessian.
